# Autohotkey script thats delete everything exept words in list

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I am new to Autohotkey and i will make a script that deletes everything exept words in document.

example:

```
> /Users/Admin/Application groups User Group    Users HyRAM
> /Users/Admin/Application groups User Group    Users PHAWorks
> /Users/Admin/Application groups User Group    Users Proteus
> /Users/Admin/Application groups User Group    Users RBMII
> /Users/Admin/Application groups User Group    Users SAFETI
```

This needs to be the output:

```
- HyRAM
- PHAWorks
- Proteus
- RBMII
- SAFETI
```

How can we do this easily?

This is what i foundbut its not working how i want :)

```
vText := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
MsgBox, % RegExReplace(vText, "^.*?m")
```

Comment: If the data is always in that format, you should split by a space and only keep the last one

Comment: The regex pattern to match the last word in a line of text is `\w+$`. To explain: `\w` is a word character, `+` looks for one or more of that type of character, `$` is the end of the line, meaning the match must occur just before the end of the line.  With that pattern, you could extract the text you desire, wipe the file and write new text into the file.

Comment: The regex pattern to match everything except the last word in a line of text is `^.*(?=\s\w+$)`. To explain: `^` is the start of a line, meaning the match must start at the beginning of the line. `.` matches any character. `.*` together means match all characters. `(?=\s\w+$)` is a lookahead, which means to look for this sub-pattern, putting this after `.*` means the match must end when this sub-pattern is found. The sub-pattern is the same as in my comment above with added `\s` (space character).

Comment: If i copy this from the shell how can i use this? ^.*(?=\s\w+$)